# Uncaught TypeError: Modernizr.mq is not a function

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I get uncaught TypeError: Modernizr.mq is not a function on my site when external ads appear on the page.
It looks as if these ads also use modernizr. Seems like two different versions of modernizr are used, my own custom Modernizr and the ads Modernizr. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I changed name of the Modernizr-object to Modernizr1. Is that ok? It works anyway..

Answer (score -3):

Depends on your modernizr version but mq is not always supported, instead you should use :

```
Modernizr.mediaqueries
```